# Nested ScrollView in swift ui doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, scrollview

I am trying to make an app in Swift in Xcode, I have a HomePage with a Scrollview (within that another view with a ScrollView), in the preview of HomePage it scrolls correctly all the way to the bottom, but when I use HomePage in my ContentView and look at the preview there it doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom.

I tried adding the `.frame(maxHeight: .infinity)` to the `HomePage()` in the ContentView Code.

(ContentView code below) Here you can only scroll to Pokemon 90 and see half of two other pokemon. (should be able to see 151 pokemon):

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            BackgroundColorView()
            TabView {
                NavigationView {
                    HomePage()
                }.tabItem {
                    Image("pokeball") .renderingMode(.template)
                    Text("Pokemon").bold()
                }
```

(HomePage code below) Here the scrolling does work correctly.
Here you can scroll through all pokemon till nr 151

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            BackgroundColorView()
            ScrollView {
                PokemonGridView(searchInput: searchInput, favourite: false)
                    .environmentObject(detailStore)
                    .environmentObject(favourites)
                    .environmentObject(evolutionStore)
                    .environmentObject(pokemonStore)
            }
        }
    }
```

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You should move everything out of the `ZStack` if you only use it for a background color and use the `.background()` modifier instead. Maybe this will fix your problem too.